Proving a limit using the squeeze theorem
Given $\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x) = 0$ and $\lvert g(x) \rvert \leq M$ for all $x \neq c$ and $M$ is a positive fixed number, prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to c} f(x)g(x) = 0$.
I begin by writing an inequality:
$$ -M \leq g(x) \leq M $$
Multiplying both sides by $f(x)$:
$$ -Mf(x) \leq f(x)g(x) \leq Mf(x) $$
Taking the limit:
$$ \lim \limits_{x \to c} -Mf(x) \leq \lim \limits_{x \to c} f(x)g(x) \leq \lim \limits_{x \to c} Mf(x) $$
$$ -M(0) \leq \lim \limits_{x \to c} f(x)g(x) \leq M(0) $$
$$ 0 \leq \lim \limits_{x \to c} f(x)g(x) \leq 0 $$
$$ \lim \limits_{x \to c} f(x)g(x) = 0 $$
Looking at an answer sheet I see that you are supposed to multiply the inequality by $\lvert f(x)\rvert$:
$$ -M\lvert f(x)\rvert \leq \lim \limits_{x \to c} f(x)g(x) \leq M\lvert f(x) \rvert $$
Is doing it my way wrong? If so, why?

Hint: think about what happens if $f(x)<0$.

If you have a inequality $a
\leq b$ and $c$ is a nonnegative number, then you can say $ac\leq bc$. But if $c$ is negative then $ac\geq bc$. Here you don't know that $f(x)$ is always positive. So the inequality will be reversed if it's negative. Now writing $|f(x)|$ solves this problem because it is always nonnegative.

I see, because we are given only $\lim \limits_{x \to c} f(x) = 0$, the value of $f(c)$ is unknown, and as such, it may be either positive or negative.

Even if f(c) is positive there might be some nearby f(x) which are negative. So still you should not use f(x) without the modulus.

I believe I understand now. As $\lvert g(x) \rvert \leq M$ only for $x ≠ c$, we only consider the sign of $f(x)$ for $x$ near $c$, and not $f(c)$ specifically. Since we don't know the sign of $f(x)$ near $x = c$, we have to consider both cases, which is simplified using the absolute-value notation.

Exactly. @ZSK3914
